# Visual Studio Code: Deploy to azure appears to work but no files seem to transfer

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I am trying to deploy my node app to Azure following the instructions below...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01

Everything appears to work, the progress bar runs for a couple of minutes in VS code and I get the deployment to  complete message. But when i got to .scm.azurewebsites.net and look in SSH for files nothing is listed in the directory apart from the holding page and when I browse to the app address in a browser I just get the holding page.

I am having similar trouble with FTP transfer updating as well. I cant seem to get any of the deployment options in the web app service working in azure, tried a few different apps in different ways. The deployments don't return errors but the changed files never make it to the destination directory.

Worth noting I am not an administrator of my employers Azure tenant.

Additional: I attempted created a new app service from VS CODE and it returned this error. I need to be able to tell my tenant admin exactly what permissions I'm to be granted. Would this be "Web app services write" or something along those lines.

```
The client '{MY EMAIL}' with object id '{GUID REMOVED}' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{GUID REMOVED}/resourceGroups/appsvc_linux_centralus/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/appsvc_linux_centralus' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Additional 2: I've also been working on a more basic web app that contains no node packages an empty node hello world and those deployments seem to work which makes me wonder if this is related to the size of the deployment. I created both apps in the in the azure app service interface, same settings but the larger app (which is actually an adapted Microsoft Echo bot Sample) wont deploy. The smaller app (Microsoft Hello World node sample) seems to work.

Comment: This isnt an answer but I'm taking an alternative approach... I've now gone down the deploy via FTP route using filezilla. The mistake I made last time was I forgot to exclude the node_modules folder possibly causing the transfer to time out. The node_modules shouldnt be copied over.

When using FTP to deploy a node app in azure you will need to trigger the NPM install manually. I did this from the SSH console. add "scm" between your app name and the domain name in your web apps address.

<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.com

Comment: This appears to be working so far but my concern now is that my app is typescript and typescript aps dont have a index.js file on the root folder. It has server.js in dist instead. I hope azure will figure this out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try using FTP to deploy my app instead of local git as I was experiencing some difficulty. Crucial mistake I made first time using FTP was I attempted to upload the node_modules folder as well. This failed probably due to the connection timing out.

Second attempt I decided to use filezilla as a client as sometimes file explorer shows duplicates that aren't there or caches views of files.

Key steps involved...

1. Download Filezilla and follow these steps to connect to your azure site
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/
2. Upload your files but exclude the node_modules folder
3. Go to you azure SSH console (add scm to your app web address between teh app name and domain... e.g .scm.azurewebites.com) then click SSH on the top menu.
4. type the following command into the SSH console
   npm install
5. Restart your web app from the azure web app portal page.

The local git, git hub and devops pipeline options are probably easier than this route probably best to set those up if you can but I couldn't get those working.